# Jitsi REST api: pass authentication

Tags: rest, authentication, jitsi, jitsi-meet

We want to use the [Jitsi REST API](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-videobridge/blob/master/doc/rest-colibri.md) to create a conference. Our Jitsi instance is already protected by Prosody: only certain users can host a conference (they have to authenticate with user and password credentials to host the room). Now after they did that, the plan is to protect the room by creating a guest-password, which needs to be entered by the chat partners/guests in order for them to join the conference. And exactly this process needs to be automated through the REST API: we want to create the conference through the REST api and pass a password, which needs to be entered by the guest. Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Look into JWT tokens. It might help with your case.